# How to execute functions with parameters in the parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, directive

Sometimes it is necessary to call a function defined in the parent scope from a directive with isolated scope. To refer to functions defined in outer scope usually `&` is used. But it doesn't allow to send params in the function. I can make it work only with `=` directive data binding. Please, consider my example on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OBESD45cmp8HhBh8w5pW?p=preview) and let me know if it is possible to use `&` and put data in a callback function.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  function updateNumber(number){
    $scope.randomNumber = number;
  }
  $scope.randomNumber = 0;
  $scope.updateNumber = updateNumber;
});

app.directive('randomGenerator', function(){
  return {
    scope:{
      onUpdate:'='
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      // I want to use '&', but cannot call onUpdate(something)
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="update()">Random</button>',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
        scope.update = function(){
          var random = Math.random();
          scope.onUpdate(random);
        };
    }
  };
});
```

Html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Random numbers generator </h1>
    <random-generator on-update="updateNumber"></random-generator>
    {{randomNumber}}
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/y0s43VQwpDb6Jyx3HzX9?p=preview

more info https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/3CHdR_THaNw

**HTML:**

```
      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1>Random numbers generator </h1>
         <!-- Add name oF parametr in your directive [NUMBER] -->
        <random-generator on-update="updateNumber(number)"></random-generator>
        {{randomNumber}}
      </body>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('randomGenerator', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onUpdate: '&'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<button ng-click="update()">Random</button>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.update = function() {
        var random = Math.random();

//passing parameter should be named and the name needs to match that on in HTML [NUMBER]
        scope.onUpdate({
          number: random
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```